# dax two columns has isKey=true

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I create date table in Microsoft tabular model.

The source `code` is :

```
{
    "name": "Дата",
    "dataCategory": "Time",
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "DateID",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "DateID",
        "sourceProviderType": "Integer"
      },
      {
        "name": "FullDateAlternateKey",
        "dataType": "dateTime",
        "isHidden": true,
        "isKey": true,
        "sourceColumn": "FullDateAlternateKey",
        "formatString": "General Date",
        "sourceProviderType": "DBDate"
      },
      {
        "name": "DayNumberOfWeek",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "DayNumberOfWeek",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "DayNameOfWeek",
        "dataType": "string",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "DayNameOfWeek",
        "sourceProviderType": "WChar"
      },
      {
        "name": "DayNumberOfMonth",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "DayNumberOfMonth",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "DayNumberOfYear",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "DayNumberOfYear",
        "sourceProviderType": "SmallInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "Неделя",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "WeekNumberOfYear",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "Месяц",
        "dataType": "string",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "MonthName",
        "sourceProviderType": "WChar"
      },
      {
        "name": "MonthNumberOfYear",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "MonthNumberOfYear",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "Квартал",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "CalendarQuarter",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "Год",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "CalendarYear",
        "sourceProviderType": "SmallInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "Полугодие",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "CalendarSemester",
        "sourceProviderType": "UnsignedTinyInt"
      },
      {
        "name": "IsWeekend",
        "dataType": "boolean",
        "isHidden": true,
        "sourceColumn": "IsWeekend",
        "formatString": "\"TRUE\";\"TRUE\";\"FALSE\"",
        "sourceProviderType": "Boolean"
      }
    ],
    "partitions": [
      {
        "name": "Дата",
        "source": {
          "query": "SELECT [dbo].[DimDate].* FROM [dbo].[DimDate]",
          "dataSource": "SqlServer MS-SQL2MSSQLTEST GoodWillDW"
        },
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "QueryEditorSerialization",
            "value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><Gemini xmlns=\"QueryEditorSerialization\"><AnnotationContent><![CDATA[<RSQueryCommandText>SELECT [dbo].[DimDate].* FROM [dbo].[DimDate]</RSQueryCommandText><RSQueryCommandType>Text</RSQueryCommandType><RSQueryDesignState></RSQueryDesignState>]]></AnnotationContent></Gemini>"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Try to deploy solution on server and have an error Cannot deploy `metadata`.

> Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The table 'Дата' has two columns with the IsKey property set to True.

But in code it seems ONE isKey attribute!!!!!
What is going on in this tabular models???
Where did it find two columns????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tables have an intrinsic special "RowNumber" column, that will have its IsKey property set to true by default. Sometimes, depending on how you're deploying the change, this will conflict with setting IsKey to true on another column of the table.

Usually, scripting out the table in a `createOrReplace` TMSL operation will solve the problem:

```
{   
  "createOrReplace": {
    "object": {
      "database": "MyDatabase",
      "table": "Дата"
    }, 
    "table": {
      "name": "Дата",
      "dataCategory": "Time",
      "columns": [
        ...
        {
          "name": "FullDateAlternateKey",
          "dataType": "dateTime",
          "isHidden": true,
          "isKey": true,
          "sourceColumn": "FullDateAlternateKey",
          "formatString": "General Date",
          "sourceProviderType": "DBDate"
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try to delete the table first.